# Saving and Getting Data / Rows to and from PouchDB

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb

i am very new to pouchdb, meaning i have not yet been successfully able to implement an app that uses it.

This is my issue now, in my controller i have two functions:

```
var init = function() {
    vm.getInvoicesRemote(); // Get Data from server and update pouchDB
    vm.getInvoicesLocal(); // Get Data from pouchDB and load in view
}

init();
```

Basically in my app i have a view that shows customer invoices, now i want customers to be able to still see those invoices when they're offline.  I have seen several examples of pouchdb and couchdb but all use the "todo" example which does not really give much information.

Now i'm just confused about what the point was in me spending hours understanding couchdb and installing it if in the end i'm just going to be retrieving the data from my server using my API.

Also when the data is returned how does pouchdb identify which records are new and which records are old when appending.

Comment: put the code of  vm.getInvoicesLocal()..?

Answer (score 0):

well, i m working on same kind..!this is how i m making it work..!

```
    $scope.Lists = function () {
        if(!$rootScope.connectionFlag){
            OfflineService.getLocalOrdersList(function (localList) {
                if(localList.length > 0) {
                    $scope.List = localList;
                }
            });
        }else{
            if(!$scope.user){
            }else {
                Common.callAPI("post", '***/*************', $scope.listParams, function (data) {
                    if (data !== null) {
                        $scope.List = data.result;
                        OfflineService.bulkOrdersAdd_updateLocalDB($scope.List);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
```

so,`$scope.List` will be filled if online as well as offline based on connectionFlag

note : `OfflineService` and `Common` are services.

call method:

```
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        OfflineService.configDbsCallback(function(res) {
            if(res) {
                $scope.Lists();
            }
        });
    });
```

u can try calling `$scope.Lists();` directly..!
hope this helps u..!